# Woocommerce randomly drops guest cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site hosted on WPEngine and for some reason whenever a guest adds a product to his cart and then goes into another product's page to add it to his cart, the cart suddenly resets.

P.S: Carts are working perfectly for signed in users

Comment: check cookies/storage

Comment: @madalinivascu I already checked that and saw that it randomly replaces the user's cart cookie with another one once the user visits a different product page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a caching issue.

I've contacted my hosting provider (which is WPEngine in my case) and told them to un-cache my cart, checkout, and my_account pages and everything worked like a charm!

If you don't have caching set from your hosting provider, try disabling any caching plugin you have and see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a caching issue.

Please You can cache the browser and after again try it, select the product with guest user.